# Generic Partial View

Tags: model-view-controller, generics, view, partial-views, partial

I just want to ask if it is possible to create a partial view that accepts a generic type of parameter?

Basically, I'm creating an add form which can be used to add different types of objects (ie Products, Employee). Currently, I can create this through a PartialView which accepts my ProductsModel to render the Add Products form. However, I want to use this same form for my Add Employee.

What I have in mind is to attach the type to render via a query string and check on the code which one of these to render. I tried it but it doesn't seem to succeed.

Can someone point me to a solution? Thanks a lot! Cheers!

Comment: Am i correct in assuming that if you want to resuse the same form for many different objects the objects share common properties, and it is these and only these properties you will be using on the shared partial?

Comment: Yes, I would like to reuse the same form for different objects. However no, these objects doesn't share the same properties. For example, Products would have ProductID, ProductName, and Price while Employee would have EmployeeID, Name, and Birthdate. And yes, these are the only properties I will be using on the shared partial. Thank you for the response!

Comment: So when you are talking about checking the query string - you want to do this within the view to figure out which property to bind? 
If that's the case you need to rethink - this is wrong on so many levels!

Comment: No, what I meant was I want to attach for example the keyword "Type" to a query string from the Main View to the rendered Partial View. So on the Partial View, I can access the keyword to figure out which properties to bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a suggestion for an alternate approach that MAY give you the functionality you need.

Declare a ViewModel object called e.g. "WidgetModel" with "n" properties - call them Property1, Property2, etc

Map the objects that you want to bind to the view, to this common object - you can use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) to achieve this very easily.

Now in the view you will be binding to the properties of the WidgetModel object and there will be no problem with types.

Personally though, I think I stick with separate partials!

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for this but your last line was right. I'm sticking with partials now too. I just realized that at the very least sticking with separate partials would make my application very maintainable. Thank you very much! :)